# Django2.0 sending and receiving message frame-work

Tags: django, django-2.0

I am new at Django. What framework I can use to send or receive a message from one user to another. What is the framework that is easy to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django Channel to start a websocket for continuous network connections: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

You can use Django Channel in addition with Django Rest Framework for your Django backend to communicate with the frontend chat client.